# pl/sql Oracle syntax

Tags: oracle, migration, query, plsql

I have a query in pl/sql that i need to migrate to ms sql.

select count(*) from table1 t1
where (conditions1) and (conditions2) and variable = t1.column1(+)

Could anyone tell me what the (+) after the column means ? (is it sort of a sum ?)

Comment: Probably better suited for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an alternate form of specifying an outer join.  There are more details here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/queries006.htm